# Stupidly simple TCP client/server

Tags: c, performance, socket, tcp

I'm trying to validate some results that I see when using [NetPipe](http://www.scl.ameslab.gov/netpipe/) to test some connectivity between a couple of Linux boxes (over various hardware). So, I concocted this simple client and server to do the same and I cannot seem to get the same numbers as NetPipe - I'm about 30-40% off the rtt times that it sees.

Is there something stupid that I'm doing wrong with my simple example?

**Server:**

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), bind(), and connect() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for perror() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit() */

#define MAXPENDING 1

void die(char *errorMessage)
{
  perror(errorMessage);
  exit(1);
}

void handle(unsigned short quickAck, int clntSock)
{
  long long c_ts;                     /* current read timestamp */
  int value = 1;

  // Enable quickAck
  if (quickAck && setsockopt(clntSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (char *)&value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    die("TCP_QUICKACK failed");

  /* Send received string and receive again until end of transmission */
  while (recv(clntSock, (char*)&c_ts, sizeof(c_ts), 0) == sizeof(c_ts))      /* zero indicates end of transmission */
  {
    // Enable quickAck
    if (quickAck && setsockopt(clntSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (char *)&value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
      die("TCP_QUICKACK failed");

    /* Echo message back to client */
    if (send(clntSock, (char*)&c_ts, sizeof(c_ts), 0) != sizeof(c_ts))
      die("send() failed to send timestamp");

    // Enable quickAck
    if (quickAck && setsockopt(clntSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (char *)&value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
      die("TCP_QUICKACK failed");
  }

  close(clntSock);    /* Close client socket */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int servSock;                    /* Socket descriptor for server */
  int clntSock;                    /* Socket descriptor for client */
  struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Local address */
  struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; /* Client address */
  unsigned short echoServPort;     /* Server port */
  unsigned short quickAck;
  unsigned int clntLen;            /* Length of client address data structure */
  int value = 1;


  if (argc != 3)     /* Test for correct number of arguments */
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage:  %s <Server Port> <Quick Ack>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  echoServPort = atoi(argv[1]);  /* First arg:  local port */
  quickAck = atoi(argv[2]);      /* Whether quick ack is enabled or not */

  /* Create socket for incoming connections */
  if ((servSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    die("socket() failed");

  /* Construct local address structure */
  memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
  echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* Internet address family */
  echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any incoming interface */
  echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);      /* Local port */

  /* Bind to the local address */
  if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
    die("bind() failed");

  /* Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections */
  if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
    die("listen() failed");

  for (;;) /* Run forever */
  {
    /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */
    clntLen = sizeof(echoClntAddr);

    printf("Waiting for client...\n");

    /* Wait for a client to connect */
    if ((clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &clntLen)) < 0)
      die("accept() failed");

    /* clntSock is connected to a client! */

    printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(echoClntAddr.sin_addr));

    if (setsockopt(clntSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
      die("TCP_NODELAY failed");

    handle(quickAck, clntSock);
  }
  /* NOT REACHED */
}
```

**Client:**

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <sys/time.h>

void die(char *errorMessage)
{
  perror(errorMessage);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                        /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Echo server address */
    unsigned short echoServPort;     /* Echo server port */
    char *servIP;                    /* Server IP address (dotted quad) */
    int iterations, gap, i;          /* Number of timestamps to send, and gap between each send */
    struct timeval ts;
    long long c_ts, o_ts, delta, total = 0, max = 0, min = 1000000000;
    int value = 1;

    if (argc != 5)    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP> <Server Port> <Iterations> <Gap>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(1);
    }

    servIP = argv[1];              /* server IP address (dotted quad) */
    echoServPort = atoi(argv[2]);  /* server port */
    iterations = atoi(argv[3]);    /* number of timestamps to send */
    gap = atoi(argv[4]);           /* gap between each send */

    /* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        die("socket() failed");

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));     /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;             /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   /* Server IP address */
    echoServAddr.sin_port        = htons(echoServPort); /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the echo server */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        die("connect() failed");

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
      die("TCP_NODELAY failed");

    /* Give the server a chance */
    usleep(1000);

    /* Now for the given number of iterations */
    for(i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
      /* Generate the current timestamp */
      gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
      c_ts = ts.tv_sec * 1000000LL + ts.tv_usec;

      //printf("sending %ld ", c_ts);

      /* Send this */
      if (send(sock, (char*)&c_ts, sizeof(c_ts), 0) != sizeof(c_ts))
        die("send() failed to send timestamp");

      /* Now read the echo */
      if (recv(sock, (char*)&o_ts, sizeof(o_ts), 0) != sizeof(o_ts))
        die("recv() failed to read timestamp");

      gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
      c_ts = ts.tv_sec * 1000000LL + ts.tv_usec;

      /* Calculate the delta */
      delta = c_ts - o_ts;

      //printf(" -> received %ld %ld\n", o_ts, delta);

      if (i > 0)
      {
        /* Track max, min, sum */
        total += delta;
        max = (max < delta)? delta : max;
        min = (min > delta)? delta : min;
      }

      /* Now sleep */
      usleep(1000*gap);
    }
    --iterations;
    printf("iterations %d, avg %f, max %ld, min %ld\n", iterations, (total/(double)iterations), max, min);

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

So, to run, start the server with the port and whether quick_ack is enabled or not (1/0) - this is for a different test. Something like:

```
./simple_sever 10000 1
```

Then run the client:

```
./simple_client <host IP address> 10000 1000 1
```

So send 1000 timestamps with a 1 millisecond gap between each. This, I guess, is where the above differs from NetPipe (which floods, as far as I know).

The interaction is pretty straight forward, so is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:** Okay, I got to the bottom of the difference: caching. NetPIPE has an option to force invalidation of cache, and enabling this results in similar numbers to my test program. Phew, I don't have to re-evaluate my sockets programming! I'll leave this question up for reference I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much to comment on, this program is pretty straightforward.  A few notes:

- The user of the client has a lot of information to input.

  > ```
  >    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP> <Server Port> <Iterations> <Gap>\n", argv[0]);
  > ```

  The more the user has to enter, the steeper the initial learning curve to use the program is.  Also, I'm not sure I want the user to control the `<Iterations>` and the `<Gap>` anyways.  A malicious user might abuse this for a DOS of the server.  Eliminating those as required input and setting them in your code would be a more secure and a more user-friendly option.
- You have too many comments.

  > ```
  >    close(clntSock);    /* Close client socket */
  > ```

  For that particular example, it is quite obvious what that statement does. There are a lot of other comparable examples in this code.
- It is more common to `return 0;` when `main()` is finished, rather than to `exit(0)`.  Both will call the registered `atexit` handlers and will cause program termination though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! :) The comments are really just explicit documentation I added for posting here... The options are required to allow different types of tests to be done. I was more interested in the simple examples being correct... Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Nim Besides the input for the client (and perhaps the `return`s), I would say that this example would be considered "correct".